# Jenkins Server throws 403 while accessing rest api or using jenkins java client to create job

Tags: java, jenkins, http-status-code-403

I am trying to create a job on Jenkins using java client (https://github.com/jenkinsci/java-client-api) by calling .createJob(String jobName, String configXml) . However, Jenkins server throws 403 forbidden error.

Sample Code :

```
HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
JenkinsHttpClient client = new JenkinsHttpClient(uri, builder, "XXX", "XXX");
JenkinsServer jenkins = new JenkinsServer(client);
String sourceXML = readFile("src/main/resources/config.xml");
System.out.println(String.format("Installed Jenkins Version >> %s", jenkins.getVersion().getLiteralVersion()));//works and gives correct result
jenkins.createJob("test-nov1", sourceXML);
```

Now, error I am getting :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: status code: 403, reason phrase: Forbidden
    at com.offbytwo.jenkins.client.validator.HttpResponseValidator.validateResponse(HttpResponseValidator.java:11)
    at com.offbytwo.jenkins.client.JenkinsHttpClient.post_xml(JenkinsHttpClient.java:375)
    at com.offbytwo.jenkins.JenkinsServer.createJob(JenkinsServer.java:389)
    at com.offbytwo.jenkins.JenkinsServer.createJob(JenkinsServer.java:359)
    at com.hcl.OffByTwoJenkins.main(OffByTwoJenkins.java:31)
```

Jenkins Server security :
When I select "Any user can do any thing", job creation is successful. However, when I select "Logged In user can do any thing", I am getting the above error. Moreover, even though I am sending correct user and password, with all permission to create job ( able to create a job using Jenkins web UI).
What permission or setting change is required to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue try by unchecking **"Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits"** in **jenkins.com/configureSecurity** section and it started working.

Comment: Sorry, this is already unchecked Sukhjinderji. I did that already but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use an API token to create JenkinsHttpClient to avoid this issue.

```
JenkinsHttpClient jenkinsHttpClient = new JenkinsHttpClient(new URI("http://192.168.0.11:8080"),
            "admin", "your api token");
```

You can generate an api token from jenkins dashboard (Jenkins> Users > Select a user> settings > add new api token).

Answer (score 0):

For me, using `true` for `crumbFlag` helped: e.g. you should call `jenkins.createJob("test-nov1", sourceXML, true);` instead of `jenkins.createJob("test-nov1", sourceXML);`